# Not able to view branches of remote repository github

Tags: git, github

I have forked a git repository and cloned it on my desktop. I have another developer who has also forked this repository and has a version much ahead of the original repository (not merged to original).

I added his repository as a remote by doing `git add remote origin http://github.com/xyx/name.git`

However when I check the list of branches using `git branch -v -a` I do not find his branches. What is the correct way to go about this?

Comment: Did you `git fetch origin` after adding the remote?

Comment: @PSkocik Yes I did git fetch

Comment: Interesting. I think that should work provided that the branches have been pushed and are on github.

Comment: I went ahead and tried it out. 
I set up a repo with two branches at `https://github.com/pjump/testrepo`  and either 1) cloning from there or 2) starting a new local repo, adding the github repo as origin, and fetching gets me both of the branches as expected.

Comment: @PSkocik It started working. I removed the remote branch and readded it using git remote set-url origin git://new.url.here

Answer (score 0):

You would have to `git fetch` or a `git pull` from the new origin to, in a sense, clone the new repo. By adding the remote, you simply created a channel from which you can get the new data; however, if you haven't done a git fetch, you haven't actually received anything from his repository yet. This is why the branches are not showing up - you haven't requested them yet.

I wouldn't recommend doing this though. If they are forked, keep them apart. Clone his repo into another one.

Comment: I have done a git fetch already. It did not get the branches from the other clone